# What kind of lawn grass doesn't spread and is exceptionally shade tolerant?

Tags: identification, lawn, grass

This grass is a very good lawn grass, showed mowed and unmowed, and I would like to buy seeds for it. Of course, I can't do that unless I know what it is. It does not spread, it doesn't turn brown during winter or during droughts, and it is exceptionally shade tolerant. What kind of grass is it?

*Click below images to enlarge...*

[image: Unknown grass type]
[image: Unknown grass type]

Comment: My initial thought was the *weed* "[Annual Bluegrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poa_annua)". Take a look here: [The Cool-season Turfgrasses: Identification](http://cropsoil.psu.edu/turf/extension/factsheets/cool-season-turfgrasses-ID) & here: [Turfgrass Species for Pennsylvania](http://cropsoil.psu.edu/turf/extension/factsheets/species) from Penn State University. If it's a desirable grass type for a lawn, I'm wondering if it's "Rough bluegrass" instead (taking into account your location)...

Comment: That is not it.

Comment: It's not what? Then please explain why it's not. I'm not questioning you, but your explanation might give helpful information we can use in further identification...

Comment: It is not either of the grasses mentioned above. I have some of them as well.

Comment: Ok! can you please try to give more information on the unknown glass eg Its blade structure. Also did you try to identify it via [The Cool-season Turfgrasses: Identification](http://cropsoil.psu.edu/turf/extension/factsheets/cool-season-turfgrasses-ID)?

Comment: @Mike Perry I tried the idenifier before. What do you want to know about the blades?

Comment: Using that identification guide can you please describe, "Vernation", "Leaf Blades", "Ligules & Auricles", "Growth Habit" (which you've already done in your question), & "The Seed Head"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is [tall fescue](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=tall%20fescue&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CGkQFjAG&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Festuca_arundinacea&ei=8yRrT62SMYX00gGu9K22Bg&usg=AFQjCNFZ-5v6uCOeQVurQ8CfAZm0pE9j3w), a common lawn grass in cool region areas. I found the answer by planting different grass seed types until I found one that matched.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That looks like fescue to me.  Fescue does not spread (with the exception of some rhizomous varieties) and is very shade tolerant.  It's down side is that it will need a lot of water in hot/dry climates if it is not in the shade.

Comment: Those links seem to be missing now.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible that you have Buffalograss ( http://www.outsidepride.com/seed/grass-seed/buffalo-grass-seed.html ). Beware: it grows fast.

I planted tall fescue in all the shaded and highly damp spots in my lawn (mostly areas shaded by the patio). While it is a completely different grass to my Blue Couch lawn (crab grass), it blends in perfectly when they're mowed at the same height.